# Thinkpad T60P video driver

Tags: drivers, video, thinkpad

I see no video drivers on my t60P thinkpad.  The video hardware is Intel on-board graphics.  Are there specific drivers for this laptop?

Comment: All Intel Graphics use open source drivers already included, no user action necessary.

Comment: @MichaelBay that qualifies as an answer...  :)

Comment: OK, I rather have more substantial answers but that would imply also more substantial questions...

Answer (score 0):

All Intel Graphics use open source drivers already included, no user action necessary.

There are no Lenovo Thinkpad T60P specific drivers.